# Only perform page.evaluate() when page.goto(url) actually loads the page

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've created a crawler that the website, https://www.sportstoto.com.my/results_past.asp?date=M/DD/yyyy
(e.g. https://www.sportstoto.com.my/results_past.asp?date=5/1/2021)

My code, takes in the start and end month and goes through each day of each month that has a lotto result, then goes specifically to each result's URL, e.g. https://www.sportstoto.com.my/popup_past_results.asp?drawNo=5277/21 and scrapes the result to be returned in JSON format. All works except for one particular month, https://www.sportstoto.com.my/results_past.asp?date=6/6/2021 where each of the clickable results does not prompt a new page but a pop-up alert instead.

How do I write my code to handle this such that I don't want to perform the page.evaluate if page.goto(url) doesn't actually renders the page but calls a pop-up

```js
 const finalUrl = result_url + drawNum;
  // await page.goto(finalUrl, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
  await page.goto(finalUrl, {waitUntil: 'load'});
  
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let root_url = "https://www.sportstoto.com.my/";
    const results = {};
    const drawDetails = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div#popup_container * span.txt_black6')).map(e => e.innerText);
```

Thanks and looking forward to some advice or guidance.

Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `page.on("dialog")` and `page.on("domcontentloaded")` to handle different page events. ref: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v9.1.1&show=api-event-dialog